# Where to put images in wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress, path

I'm converting a precoded website to wordpress based website.

All the URLs are currently `img/file_name`

In wordpress im using a basic `page.php` with 3 functions, `get_header() get_body() get_footer()` in which my pages are split into 3 parts and the middle content is made into wordpress page posts.

The middle content often contains images, how do I go about linking to them correctly?

Where should I put the img folder as what path should I call, i dont know where im referencing from with wordpress being dynamic.

At the moment img is in my theme directory and the images are missing. Are they not relative to page.php which is inside my theme also?

Answer (score 2):

If the images are in your theme folder, you can use the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function.

```
<img src="<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/whatever.jpg' ?>">
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: Yeah, i have a page template, so im adding the images with html not php. Looks like im just gonna have to hard code all the paths.

Comment: All wp templates are php files??

Comment: Yeah, the website is precoded in html. I made a page.php file with get_header() get_content() get_footer() and pasting the content of each premade page into the content.

Comment: @user2979139 Oh I understand, you are copying html code directly into the wp editor  field. This is usually a sign of poor design - an admin who is not proficient with html can easily break the site. You would be better creating multiple page templates and adding the code directly into the template

Comment: Since the website is for personal use and ill be the only person touching the admin theres not going to be anyone messing it up, ive gone with hardcoded paths as the domain is unlikely to change, but i see where you're coming from with making each page a template, ill bare that in mind in future, if a similar situation arised.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the images in the `wp-content/uploads` folder.

You would like using "http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/yourimage.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress allows you to [add pictures](http://en.support.wordpress.com/images/) (and more) when adding/editing articles and posts

Take a look at -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Images which also covers working with images in themes.